mobile menu items are not clickable
Lately we applied a new style to our website
the mobile menu items  are not clickable neither main menu items nor the sub menu items .
here is the website link
https://www.creative-academy.net
if you try to open using mobile browser the menu items are not  clickable .
please help me solve this
I tried the new design in the safari browser and the edge browser
same problem appears in both
Mobile menu is not clickable 
The following is the source code of the menu:

        <header class="site-navbar py-4 js-sticky-header site-navbar-target" role="banner">

            <div class="container">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                    <div class="site-logo">
                        <a href="index.html" class="d-block">
                            <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mr-auto">
                        <nav class="site-navigation position-relative text-right" role="navigation">
                            <ul class="site-menu main-menu js-clone-nav mr-auto d-none d-lg-block">
                                <li class="active">
                                    <a href="index.aspx" class="nav-link text-left">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="has-children">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link text-left">About Us</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown">
                                        <li>
                                            <asp:HyperLink ID="hypHome2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="OurTeachers.aspx"> Our Teachers</asp:HyperLink></li>
                                        <li>
                                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="GeneralManager.aspx">General Manager</asp:HyperLink></li>
                                        <li>
                                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="GirlsPrincipal.aspx">Girls Principal</asp:HyperLink></li>
                                        <li>
                                            <asp:HyperLink ID="hypabout" runat="server" NavigateUrl="AcademicDirector.aspx">Academic Director</asp:HyperLink></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="has-children">
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hypadmissions" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#">Admissions</asp:HyperLink>
                                    <ul class="dropdown">
                                        <li>
                                            <asp:HyperLink ID="hypFees" runat="server" NavigateUrl="Fees.aspx">Fees Structure</asp:HyperLink></li>
                                        <%--Fees.aspx--%>

                                        <li>
                                            <asp:HyperLink Target="_blank" ID="hypSchoolDisc" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#">School Discipline</asp:HyperLink></li>

                                        <li>
                                            <asp:HyperLink Target="_blank" ID="hypOnlineRegistration" runat="server" NavigateUrl="https://forms.office.com/r/uX2xBupX4K">Online Registration</asp:HyperLink></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="has-children">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link text-left">E-School</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown">
                                        <li><a target="_blank" href="https:Classlight.com">Classlight Login</a></li>
                                        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://my.mheducation.com/">MacGraw Hill Login</a></li>
                                        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://schools.madrasati.sa/">Madrasati Login</a></li>
                                        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.cambridge.org/sa/education/subject/english/first-language-english/cambridge-primary-and-lower-secondary-english-2nd-edition">Cambridge Login</a></li>


                                        <li><a href="Login.aspx">Login</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li class="has-children">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link text-left">Gallery</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="Facilities.aspx" class="nav-link text-left">Facilities</a>
                                        <a href="gallery.aspx" class="nav-link text-left">Albums</a>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="Contact.aspx" class="nav-link text-left">Contact</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="Career.aspx" class="nav-link text-left">Careers</a>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>

                    </div>
                    <div class="ml-auto">
                        <div class="social-wrap">
                            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/dammam.creative.school"><span class="icon-facebook"></span></a>
                            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/creative_international_school"><span class="icon-instagram"></span></a>
                            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/@creativeinternationalschool"><span class="icon-youtube"></span></a>

                            <a href="#" class="d-inline-block d-lg-none site-menu-toggle js-menu-toggle text-black"><span
                                class="icon-menu h3"></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </header>


I doubt the problem lies with the HTML alone so we'd need to see relevant JS. Have you used your browser's devtools inspect facility to see if there are any errors in the console? (There are - get those cured first and see what happens - in particular you are using a deprecated mutation event.)
